# Kissing the Monster, or $196,560$ vs. $196,883$

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, sphere-packing, monster

The $D = 24$ kissing number is $196,560$, and the dimension of the smallest non-trivial complex representation of the Monster group is $196,883$. These two numbers are nearly but not quite equal, and I'm wondering where the discrepancy comes from.

Both quantities are derived from the Leech lattice. The kissing number is the number of minimal length vectors in the lattice, whereas the Monster group has a more convoluted link: one first compactifies bosonic string theory on (a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ orbifold of (the torus defined by)) the Leech lattice, then takes the degree $2$ part of the corresponding vertex algebra, known as the Griess algebra, which has the Monster as its automorphism group. So, you can see why I don't consider "the Leech lattice" as a sufficient answer to this question; the fact that these two values are both related to the Leech lattice doesn't really explain why they should be so close to one another.

The situation in dimension $8$ is similar, but I have an explanation there. The kissing number is $240$, the reason being the same as in $24$ dimensions, just with the $E_8$ lattice in place of $\Lambda_{24}$, whereas the dimension of the Lie group/algebra $E_8$ is $248$. The difference between the two is $8$, but this is easily seen to come from the rank of $E_8$, coming from the $8$-dimensional Cartan subalgebra of the Lie algebra whose root lattice is the $E_8$ lattice. What I'm asking, then, is: *what is the 24 dimensional analogue of the Cartan subalgebra explanation?*

Comment: Holy click bait, Batman! :)

Comment: The $196\,884$-dimensional Griess algebra is constructed without any reference to string theory in chapter 29 of Conway & Sloane's *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*, where $196\,884$ appears as $300 + 98\,304 + 98\,280$ (“where $300$ is the symmetric tensor square of $24$, and $98\,304$ the tensor product $4096\otimes 24$”). The next chapter speculates on the existence of a possible “Monster Lie algebra”, which is perhaps what you're after.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Yes, of course one doesn't need string theory to construct the Monster -- the Monster existed before moonshine! I think you might have the answer there, though, since $196884 - 196560 = 300 + 24$, but it would be nice to see this written up in full. For example, is this "Monster Lie algebra" still a speculative object?

Comment: One could study how the smallest-dimensional irreducible representation decomposes under the $2^{ 1+ 24} \cdot \operatorname{Co}_1$ involution centralizer subgroup and compare it to the action of $2 \cdot \operatorname{Co}_1$ on the kissing spheres in the Leech lattice.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Because the Griess algebra has dimension $196\,884$ which decomposes into the $1$-dimensional trivial representation and the $196\,883$-dimensional (first non-trivial) representation of the Monster. Though it's not completely clear (at least to me) which of $196\,884$ or $196\,883$ should be analogous to $248$ for $E_8$.